# Is there Geogebra tutorial for Beginners?

Tags: geometry, education, math-software

I teach mathematics at the High School, specifically geometry. I would be interested in learning to use the Geogebra program to make the lesson more interactive and also to create exercises with it. Is there a tutorial for someone who is a beginner?

Comment: Geogebra themselves have some useful tutorials: https://www.geogebra.org/a/14?lang=en. In particular, [GeoGebra classroom](https://www.geogebra.org/m/hncrgruu) looks perfect for your case :D

Comment: @Scene Thank you for the prompt reply